# Events Emitted in logs but not mentioned in the contracts

Tags: solidity, etherscan

Event EvProfit is the second event emitted in this [transaction on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9f9dac48ed1def0b2103f9b0a91875211f41a4dc4fe418ec5cb890a2eedd5992#eventlog). However, when i click on "view source" & get redirected to the [contracts on 0x743123](https://etherscan.io/address/0x74312363e45dcaba76c59ec49a7aa8a65a67eed3#code), I couldn't find where the event is emitted as its not mentioned in the contracts.

Why do none of the contracts called seem to emit the EvProfit event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract you pointed to is a proxy contract. It delegates inputs to an implementation contract that can change from time to time to support upgradeability. It's the implementation that does the work.

Click on "read as proxy" on the contract tab and you will see the implementation contract address. Check out the source code for that: https://etherscan.io/address/0x6d7812d41a08bc2a910b562d8b56411964a4ed88#code you will see that the event log is defined in the usual way.

Hope it helps.